# Minted variables alone vs in expressions being colorized differently

Tags: minted

We are using minted for a paper.

Variable/function names are being colorized when they stand alone in inline expressions, but not when they are part of arithmetic expressions. For example, the `n` and `2*n` below:

[image]

Is there any way to make this consistent?

EDIT: The code for the image above is:

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{minted}
```

In the document:

```
0, \mintinline{haskell}{n}, \mintinline{haskell}{2*n} etc.
in the \mintinline{haskell}{Integer} time domain,
without any side effects.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know exactly what to try. I'm not familiar enough with minted.  I tried to Google for people seeing the same thing, but found nothing. I thought about adding an empty space before `n` to make it a longer expression and hence rendered without colors, but seems like a dirty solution to me.

Comment: Please, show the code for the image

Comment: Added the code that generates that image.

Comment: `\mintinline{haskell}{n*2}` works though. `minted` uses the `Pygments` library to do the highlighting so I think that, although _on-topic_, you question requires a solution that changes the behaviour of the `Pygments` library...

Comment: The Pygments lexer for Haskell transforms the isolated `n` into `\PYG{n+nf}{n}`, but the expression `2*n` becomes `\PYG{l+m+mi}{2}\PYG{o}{*}\PYG{n}{n}`. So it's a lexer issue and little can be made on the TeX side, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks to both. This has been reported to pygments now: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1460/coloring-of-single-variables-vs-variables

If I don't see a clear solution/workaround, I'll just respond with that link and close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that there is no style attached to the `Name` token class in some of Pygments' style files in the Python code (in that case the default style). There's a style attached to `Name.Function`, however, which makes the LaTeX style class `[n+nf]` do have a color but `[n]` not.

The Pygments' LaTeX formatter creates commands like `\PYGXXXX@tok@YY` for all token classes defined in the style file, where `XXXX` is the used style scheme name and `YY` a short name for the token style class. As a quick fix to add the missing style for the `Name` token, we can just add a command alias to the preamble of our document which uses the `Name.Function` style:

```
\makeatletter
\def\PYGdefault@tok@n{\PYGdefault@tok@nf}
\makeatother
```

Note that this will use the `Name.Function` style in all situations where the `n` token comes last in the parameter list of `\PYG`, so there may still be an inconsistency in case other `nX` tokens are used in a different order in some code snippets. A quick check shows that only `n` and `nf` are used for variable names, though.

Also note that the `default` part of these command names has to be adjusted in case another style scheme is used.

---

Additional full minimal sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\def\PYGdefault@tok@n{\PYGdefault@tok@nf}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mintinline{haskell}{n}

\mintinline{haskell}{2*n}

\mintinline{haskell}{f (n*(n+1))}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I added this right before `\begin{document}`, and there was no change. I tried different alternatives and explored the generated _minted files to see how it was being generated, and I find `\PYG{n+nf}{n}` vs `\PYG{l+m+mi}{2}\PYG{o}{*}\PYG{n}{n}`. However, I'm not sure how to make those "agree". I tried to revert your code (nf goes to the left of `=` and n goes to the right), but that changed nothing. I'm not sure what else I can do. Does it work for you with a minimal minted latex file with inline haskell?

Comment: @IvanPerez Sorry, I messed up that code because of some manual tweaking I tried before. I hope the new version works better for you.

Comment: I can confirm that this works.